# Attempting to make a button in thymeleaf that increments a user's balance

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Attempting to make have options for the user that they can press a few buttons to increase the current "balance" of the "buyer". As of now, my buttons do nothing and I'm sure there is extremely stupid I'm doing on a rather easy thing. Thanks for any help in advance.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "toner_buyer")
public class Buyer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "BUYER_ID")
    private Long buyerId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "BUYER_ADDRESS")
    private String buyerAddress;

    @Column(name = "BUYER_BALANCE")
    private int balance;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "buyer")
    private Set<Toner> toners;


    public Buyer(){}

    public Buyer(String firstName, String lastName, String buyerAddress, int balance) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public Buyer(String firstName, String lastName, String buyerAddress, int balance, Set<Toner> toners) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.toners = toners;
    }

    public Set<Toner> getToners() {
        return toners;
    }

    public void setToners(Set<Toner> toners) {
        this.toners = toners;
    }

    public Long getBuyerId() {
        return buyerId;
    }

    public void setBuyerId(Long buyerId) {
        this.buyerId = buyerId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getBuyerAddress() {
        return buyerAddress;
    }

    public void setBuyerAddress(String buyerAddress) {
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class BuyerController {

    private BuyerService buyerService;

    @Autowired
    private TonerService tonerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setBuyerService(BuyerService buyerService){
        this.buyerService = buyerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add-buyer")
    public String showBuyerPager(Model model){

        //List
        List<Buyer> buyers = buyerService.findAllBuyers();
        List<Toner> toners = tonerService.findAllToners();

        //sending list to view
        model.addAttribute("buyers", buyers);
        model.addAttribute("toners", toners);

        //creating objects in view
        model.addAttribute("buyer", new Buyer());
        model.addAttribute("toner", new Toner());
        return "add-buyer";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showBuyerForm")
    public String addBuyerForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("buyer", new Buyer());
        model.addAttribute("toner", new Toner());
        model.addAttribute("buyerId", new Buyer().getBuyerId());
        return "add-buyer";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addBuyer")
    public String postBuyerForm(@ModelAttribute("buyer") Buyer buyer, Model model){
        buyerService.saveBuyer(buyer);
        model.addAttribute("buyer", new Buyer());
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/deleteBuyer/{id}")
    public String deleteBuyer(@PathVariable Long id){
        buyerService.deleteBuyer(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addToBuyerBal/{id}")
    public String addToBuyerBalance(Model model, @PathVariable Long id, @ModelAttribute("add") int add){
        Buyer mBuyer = buyerService.findOne(id);
        mBuyer.setBalance(mBuyer.getBalance() + add);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/purcahseToner/{toner}")
    public String buyToner(@PathVariable Toner toner){
        Buyer buyer = new Buyer();

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saleToner/{toner}")
    public String saleToner(){

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header> Welcome to Toner Stock </header>
<h1>Add Buyer</h1>
<div id="mynav" align="center">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="add-buyer">Add Buyer</a></li>
        <li><a href="add-manager">Add Manager</a></li>
        <li><a href="current-stock">Current Stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="transactions">Transactions</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <div id="display-table" align="center">
       <form th:action="@{/addBuyer}" th:object="${buyer}" style="width:100%" method="post">
           <table>
               <td><label>First Name: </label></td>
               <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"/></td>
               <td><label>Last Name: </label></td>
               <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"/></td>
               <td><label>Enter Address: </label></td>
               <td><input type="text" th:field="*{buyerAddress}"/></td>
               <td><input type="submit" value="save"/></td>
           </table>
       </form>
    </div>
<div>
    <div>
        <table id="info-table" align="center" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Select Toner</th>
                <th>Current Balance</th>
                <th>Add to Balance</th>
                <th>Delete Buyer</th>
                <th>Purchase Item</th>
                <th>Sale Item</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="buyer : ${buyers}">
                <td th:text="${buyer.firstName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${buyer.lastName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${buyer.buyerAddress}"></td>
                <td>
                <select>
                    <option th:each="toner : ${toners}"
                            th:text="${toner.tonerName}"
                            th:value="${toner.id}">
                    </option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td th:text="${buyer.balance}"></td>
                <td>
                    <form th:action="@{/addToBuyerBal/{id}(id=${buyer.buyerId})}" th:object="${buyer}" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" value="25" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to pay $25?')">$25</button>
                        <button type="submit" value="50" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to pay $50?')">$50</button>
                        <button type="submit" value="100" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to pay $100?')">$100</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form th:action="@{/deleteBuyer/{id}(id=${buyer.buyerId})}" th:object="${buyer}" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="${buyer}">Delete</input>
                        <button type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete a Manager?')"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form th:action="@{/purcahseToner/{toner}(toner=${buyer.toners})}" th:object="${buyer}" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{toners}">Purchase</input>
                        <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to make this purchase?')"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form th:action="@{/saleToner/{toner}(toner=${buyer.toners})}" th:object="${buyer}" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{toners}">Sale</input>
                        <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to sale this?')"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```